# Is the intuition correct?

Tags: expectation, median

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $E|X|<\infty$ and $$P\left(X\ge\frac{1}{2}+x\right)=P\left(X\le\frac{1}{2}-x\right)\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.$$ 
Then

1. $E(X)=\frac{1}{2}$ and Median($X$)$=\frac{1}{2}$
2. $E(X)=\frac{1}{2}$ and Median($X$)$>\frac{1}{2}$
3. $E(X)<\frac{1}{2}$ and Median($X$)$=\frac{1}{2}$
4. $E(X)<\frac{1}{2}$ and Median($X$)$>\frac{1}{2}$

I think option $1$ is correct as it looks (still in doubt) from the given condition that the median is $\frac{1}{2}$ and about the expectation the equation can be rewritten as $$P\left(X-\frac{1}{2}\ge x\right)=P\left(X-\frac{1}{2}\le -x \right)\\ P(Y\ge x)=P(Y\le -x)$$ this implies symmetry hence $E(Y)=0\implies E(X)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Right, the distribution of $X$ is symmetric around $1/2$ so mean of $X$ equals median of $X$ equals the point of symmetry of $X$.

Comment: oh, thanks to remind me I forgot this basic principal.

Comment: Does it also means that mode is also at the point of symmetry?,  I think not unless we know the distribution??

Comment: Correct, it can be bimodal.